# Expose methods of nested class

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop

I have a Public Class called "ClientConnection". Inside that class, I have a Public ReadOnly Property called "FileTransfers(ByVal TransferID)". The property returns an object of the class "FileTransfer". All methods in FileTransfer are set to public.

VS is able to *discover* the methods inside the parent class "ClientConnection". How would I expose the methods inside the sub-class "FileTransfer" that is returned by the property "FileTransfers(ByVal TransferID)"?

```
Public Class ClientConnection
'irreverent code removed

   Public ReadOnly Property FileTransfers(ByVal TransferID As Integer)
    Get
        Dim obj As FileTransfer = OngoingFileTransfers(TransferID)
        If obj IsNot Nothing Then
            Return obj
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Get
   End Property

End Class

Public Class FileTransfer()
  Public Sub StartTransfer() '<--- I need this discoverable in VS from ClientConnection's parent
   'do some stuff
  End Sub
End Class
```

I understand that this may be difficult to understand. So if you need me to clarify, just ask. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to indicate what type is returned by your `FileTransfers` property.

Right now, there is no `as` clause at the end of the property declaration.

```
Public ReadOnly Property FileTransfers(ByVal TransferID As Integer) as FileTransfer
 Get
     Dim obj As FileTransfer = OngoingFileTransfers(TransferID)
     If obj IsNot Nothing Then
         Return obj
     Else
         Return Nothing
     End If
 End Get
End Property
```

This sounds more like a method operation than a property though.

Comment: Wow, such a simple fix. Thanks! I'll accept this as the answer in 5 minutes